# ELBO loss in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I've read that when data is binary, the reconstruction loss is modeled by a multivariate factorized Bernoulli distribution using `torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy`, so the ELBO loss can be implemented like this:

```
def loss_function(recon_x, x, mu, logvar):
   BCE = F.binary_cross_entropy(recon_x, x.view(-1, patch_size*patch_size), reduction='sum')
   KLD = -0.5 * torch.sum(1 + logvar - mu.pow(2) - logvar.exp())
   return BCE + KLD
```

My data is not binary, how can I implement the elbo loss correctly so that it can be converge to zero?

Comment: "not binary" - then how is your data ? multi-class ? continuous ?

Comment: I don't know, I'm using a dataset that contains gray-scale images. How can I do to discover?

Comment: Images are your inputs. How many classes do you have ? What exactly is your task ? That is important to answer your question.

Comment: I'm using a Variational Autoencoder for anomaly detection. My images are unlabeled, I've a dataset that contains only the images. I have to train my VAE in an unsupervised manner.

Comment: Oh right, I misread your description, sorry.
The bianry cross entropy is because usually images are binary images. If you can binarize your images, then you can use the same. Otherwise, you need to use Gaussian distribution for each pixel. In that case, its basically a continuous distribution.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. How can I implement it? I can't find any code online.